# jq filter array of object unique property values

Tags: jq

Very simple but beginning with jq.

What I have is an array of object. I want to have an array of object filtered by unique value 'myprop'

```
[

    {
      "myProp": "similarValue"
    },
    {
      "myProp": "similarValue"
    },
    {
      "myProp": "OtherValue"
    }
]
```

Result I want:

```
[

    {
      "myProp": "similarValue"
    },
    {
      "myProp": "OtherValue"
    }
]
```

What I've tried:
.someContainerProp | unique[] .myProp

The problem is that is returns just the list of values not list of object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was pretty easy actually

.values | unique_by(.myProp)

Comment: Yes `unique_by` is probably the best solution.  In a situation where you can't use `unique_by` you could try the approach [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750116/8379597).  Also note that `unique_by` my change the relative order of the array elements.