# Unique combinations of different values in json using jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, unique, jq

I have a json file(input.json) which looks like this :

```
{"header1":"a","header2":1a, "header3":1a, "header4":"apple"},
{"header1":"b","header2":2a, "header3":2a, "header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"c","header2":1a, "header3":2a, "header4":"banana"},
{"header1":"d","header2":2a, "header3":1a, "header4":"apple"},
{"header1":"a","header2":2a, "header3":1a, "header4":"banana"},
{"header1":"b","header2":1a, "header3":2a, "header4":"orange"},
{"header1":"b","header2":1a, "header3":1a, "header4":"orange"},
{"header1":"d","header2":1a, "header3":1a, "header4":"apple"},
{"header1":"a","header2":2a, "header3":1a, "header4":"banana"} (repeat of line 5)
```

I want to filter out only the unique combinations of each of the values jq. 
Results should look like:

```
{"header1":"a","header2":1a, "header3":1a, "header4":"apple"},
{"header1":"b","header2":2a, "header3":2a, "header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"c","header2":1a, "header3":2a, "header4":"banana"},
{"header1":"d","header2":2a, "header3":1a, "header4":"apple"},
{"header1":"a","header2":2a, "header3":1a, "header4":"banana"},
{"header1":"b","header2":1a, "header3":2a, "header4":"orange"},
{"header1":"b","header2":1a, "header3":1a, "header4":"orange"},
{"header1":"d","header2":1a, "header3":1a, "header4":"apple"}
```

I tried doing group by of header1 with the other headers but it didn't generate unique results.
I've used `unique` but that didnt generate the proper results.

How can I get this? Im new to jq and not finding many tutorials on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The sample lines you give are not valid JSON.  Since your preamble introduces them as JSON, the following will assume that you intended to present an array of JSON objects.
2. The question is unclear in several respects, but from the example, it looks as though `unique` might be what you're looking for, so consider:

Invocation: jq -c 'unique[]' input.json

Output:

```
{"header1":"a","header2":"1a","header3":"1a","header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"a","header2":"2a","header3":"1a","header4":"banana"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"1a","header3":"1a","header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"1a","header3":"2a","header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"2a","header3":"2a","header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"c","header2":"1a","header3":"2a","header4":"banana"}
{"header1":"d","header2":"1a","header3":"1a","header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"d","header2":"2a","header3":"1a","header4":"apple"}
```

3. If you need the output in some other format, you could do that using jq as well, but the requirements are not so clear, so let's leave that as an exercise :-)

Comment: updated my question, please check again. I want to generate unique combinations of each value by selecting these particular keys only

Answer (score 0):

Since as [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) indicated your input isn't legal JSON I've taken the liberty of correcting it and converting to a list of individual objects:

```
{"header1":"a","header2":"1a", "header3":"1a", "header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"2a", "header3":"2a", "header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"c","header2":"1a", "header3":"2a", "header4":"banana"}
{"header1":"d","header2":"2a", "header3":"1a", "header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"a","header2":"2a", "header3":"1a", "header4":"banana"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"1a", "header3":"2a", "header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"1a", "header3":"1a", "header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"d","header2":"1a", "header3":"1a", "header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"a","header2":"2a", "header3":"1a", "header4":"banana"}
```

If this data is in `data.json` and you run

```
jq -M -s -f filter.jq data.json
```

with the following `filter.jq`

```
foreach .[] as $r (
  {}
; ($r | map(.)) as $p | if getpath($p) then empty else setpath($p;1) end
; $r
)
```

it will generate the following output in the original order with no duplicates.

```
{"header1":"a","header2":"1a","header3":"1a","header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"2a","header3":"2a","header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"c","header2":"1a","header3":"2a","header4":"banana"}
{"header1":"d","header2":"2a","header3":"1a","header4":"apple"}
{"header1":"a","header2":"2a","header3":"1a","header4":"banana"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"1a","header3":"2a","header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"b","header2":"1a","header3":"1a","header4":"orange"}
{"header1":"d","header2":"1a","header3":"1a","header4":"apple"}
```

Note that the

```
($r | map(.))
```

is used to generate an array containing just the values from each row
which is assumed to always produce a unique key path. This is true for
the sample data but may not be true for more complex values.

A slower but more robust `filter.jq` is

```
foreach .[] as $r (
  {}
; [$r | tojson] as $p | if getpath($p) then empty else setpath($p;1) end
; $r
)
```

which uses the json representation of the entire row as a unique key to determine if a row has been previously seen.